# Django {% url %} supported in AppEngine Launcher?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

With latest AppEngine is Django 1.3.

Should the Django tag   {% url   %} work in Lanucher when app run locally?

Comment: Have you tried? Do you have any reason to suspect it won't?

Comment: Yes I can not get it to work and there is things on the web saying %url has issues so I am not sure if me or launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `url` tag isn't supported when using GAE's Python 2.7. I think it came down to not finding a safe way to making the temporary monkey-patching that we do for Python 2.5 work safely with multi-threaded 2.7 apps.

Comment: At the moment, hard code URLs, or switch to Jinja2 templates.